# Android Bluetooth Speed

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm doing a feasibility analysis of a project idea that involves sending files from one android device to another over bluetooth. The files are Microsoft office documents and can vary in size, but will not probably exceed 15 mega bytes.

I want to know what file transfer speed should one expect over bluetooth?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth) the rate depends on the version of Bluetooth.

[Here](http://web.archive.org/web/20140906043716/http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_devices) you can see that almost all Android devices have at least Bluetooth 2.0 + EDR. So The nominal rate of EDR is about 3 Mbit/s, although the practical data transfer rate is 2.1 Mbit/s.

Comment: Advise me any Android or Windows software where I can see receive/transfer bluetooth speed.

Answer (score 5):

So far my experiments with Bluetooth 3.0, 4.0 and 4.1 are far from the claimed rates.
The best throughput I achieved was with Bluetooth 4.0 between a Nexus 6 and a EcoDroidLink access point with a rate of 1.7Mbps in the best case.

Between the Nexus 6 and a Windows PC (using the same USB Bluetooth 4.0 dongle), I achieve between 1.1 and 1.3Mbps for file transfers.
The phone to phone data transfer is in the same range.

Other remarks:

- measurements were done with 0ft distance between devices, at 5ft bandwidth drops to 0.8Mbps and down to 0.35Mbps at 10 ft.
- if you have simultaneous transfers (tried up to 3 phones), they share equally the bandwidth (about 0.5Mbps each at 0 ft from access point)